# Rails routing issue -- trying to post from a form but it is using "GET"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having a problem with submitting a simple form, and I'm not entirely sure what the deal is. The problem, I think, is that I'm trying to submit a form from a User's profile page to another model (ItemShare). Instead of submitting the form via post, it's trying to make a GET request. When I've changed the ItemSharesController to allow for this, it puts ItemShare#index into my modal form, even though I've specified in a billion places that I want it to post. POST!

In my routes.rb:

```
  match '/item_shares' => 'item_shares#create', :via => :post
  resources :item_shares, :except => :create
```

The form:

```
  #share-list-button-dialog.modal.hide.fade{:role => "dialog"}
    .modal-dialog
      %h3 Share List
    .modal-body
      =form_for(ItemShare.new, :method => :post, :url => {:action => "create"}) do |f|
        =f.hidden_field(:item_id, :value => item.token)
        =f.hidden_field(:owner_id, :value =>user.id)
        =f.label :shared_user_email, "Your collaborator's email:"
        =f.text_field :shared_user_email, :value => "collaborator@example.com"
        =f.submit "Share"
```

ItemSharesController:

```
class ItemSharesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @item_share = ItemShare.new
  end

  def create
    @item_share = ItemShare.new(params[:item_share])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item_share.save
        format.html {redirect_to user_path(current_user.id), :notice => "List shared successfully"}
      else
        flash.now[:alert] = "Could not share list."
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And this is what the stack trace is showing:

```
Started GET "/item_shares/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-15 21:40:44 -0400
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/item_shares"):
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  ...
```

What's going on here??

***UPDATE*** ... finally know what was up.
The form itself was not the problem, but the button I was using to trigger the modal form. I had:

`%button{'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'href' => '../item_shares/', 'data-target' => '#share-list-button-dialog'}`.

Changed it to this: 
`=button_to "Share", item_shares_path, "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#share-list-button-dialog"`

And now it's all working fine. Many thanks to Helios de Guerra for his help and patience. :)

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? From what I can tell, you're convoluting what Rails gives you by default.  Your `match '/item_shares' => 'item_shares#create', :via => :post` is exactly the route that `resources :item_shares` would create. And your form_for can just be for ItemShare.new, you shouldn't have to specify method or url.

Comment: I did the route that way after I ran into this issue. Honestly I think I tried every iteration of [rails forms](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) and routing hacks in my attempt to send a post command instead of a get. I don't even know why it's doing this... from everything I've read, POST _should_ be the default behavior. It's not that it was even trying to post to Users! It's just trying to ... GET. :(

Comment: What does the html source for your form look like?  Does it specify the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you're describing, you should just be using the standard conventions.

Routes:

```
resources :item_shares
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for(ItemShare.new) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

If it doesn't work, check the source of the rendered page.  The form markup should include something like:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/item_shares" id="new_item_share" method="post">
```

Comment: Ok, I tried your suggestion, but I am still having the same error. Even more frustrating, the form markup is exactly as it's supposed to look: `<form id="new_item_share" class="new_item_share" method="post" action="/item_shares" accept-charset="UTF-8">`  AND STILL, the stack trace shows this: Started GET "/item_shares/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-16 18:05:11 -0400

AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The action 'index' could not be found for ItemSharesController:

Comment: And that was with your routes with the simple `resources :item_shares`?  Are you sure its failing on the form submit and not just falling to your `else` statement in your create action?  Since you're not rendering or redirecting in the else statement, might it be failing for a different reason on the post, then trying to render (and therefore GET) at /item_shares?

Comment: I don't think it's even getting that far. I've tried just putting simple log notes in there. I rewrote my routes to `resources :item_shares.` My browser is showing the header request as: `Request URL: http://localhost:3000/item_shares/ 
Request Method:GET`. The stack response is still: `AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The action 'index' could not be found for ItemSharesController`

Comment: Interestingly, and I only just noticed this, I'm getting this response back from the server _before_ I submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Upon first glance, I'd say it has something to do with this `=form_for(ItemShare.new`

In my experience, Rails builds the path from the url in the form_for, which means that yours is going to be messed up with that. You might want to give this a try:

```
#users/new
  def new
    @item_share = ItemShare.new
  end

#form
 =form_for(@item_share
```

I'm not totally sure on it, but it's my hunch

Comment: I don't think that will work because I'm using Devise and Omniauth to handle the User, so all calls to User.new would need to pass the authorization.

Comment: I meant to put that code in the action that your form is on. Devise handles new user sessions with registrations#new anyways

Comment: Doing this gives me a NoMethodError.. :-/ .. Thanks for the suggestion, though.